How to study regularity of a Green's function when solving field equations perturbatively?
Preliminaries
Consider a nonlinear differential operator $\mathcal{O}$ acting on a field $\phi$, with source $\rho$
$$\mathcal{O}(\phi)=\rho$$
Let's say the charge density is small, so we can define $\rho=\epsilon \rho_{(1)}$ and expand the field as $$\phi=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^n \phi_{(n)}$$ We can expand the equations as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{O}(\phi_{(0)})&=0 \\ \delta \mathcal{O}(\phi_{(1)})&=\rho_{(1)}\\ \delta \mathcal{O}(\phi_{(2)})&=-\delta^2 \mathcal{O}\big[\phi_{(1)},\phi_{(1)}\big]\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
Where $\delta\mathcal{O}$ is the linearized version of $\mathcal{O}$ and $\delta^{2}\mathcal{O}$ is $\mathcal{O}$ expanded to second order in the fields, and so on.
Green's functions
The lineraized operator $\delta\mathcal{O}$ will determine a Green's function
$$ \delta\mathcal{O} G(x,y)=\delta (x,y)$$
such that the first order solution is
$$\phi_{(1)}(x)=\int dV' G(x,x')\rho_{(1)}(x')$$
Since the source for $\phi_{(2)}$ is quadratic in $\phi_{(1)}$, the solution will be quadratic in the charge density and will be expressed with a 3-point Green's function
$$ \phi_{(2)}(x)=\int dV'dV'' H(x,x',x'')\rho_{(1)}(x')\rho_{(1)}(x'')$$
The 3-point Green's function $H$ will satisfy
$$\delta \mathcal{O} H(x,y,z)=-\delta^2 \mathcal{O}\big[G(x,y),G(x,z)\big]$$
My question
I would like to study the regularity of the Green's functions $G$ and $H$. For example, I would like to know if they have a good limit for point particles, where we consider $\rho\rightarrow \delta(x)$. My question is: Which properties of $\mathcal{O}$, $\delta\mathcal{O}$ and $\delta^2 \mathcal{O}$ would determine that $G$ and $H$ are finite, or divergent, or regular, or not, in general and in the point particle limit?
